# How to implement dragging to scroll horizontally within a container in React?

Tags: reactjs

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-image-gallery-yp20u

I have an image gallery that can be scrolled horizontally, but how to implement a solution in React to drag to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

In ImageGallery component's section apply some fixed width as you want and apply css property overflow-x: scroll. Now when your components size increases than width you specified it displays scroll bar.

```
 <section className="images" style={{width:'200px', overflow-x:'scroll'}}>
```

More about overflow : [css-tricks.com/overflow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

Comment: your .images class does not have fixed width. please try putting some fixed width.